# Updating a Dataproc cluster (metadata or labels) directly while in initialization actions script

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

I'd like to save more specific errors in the case of a failed initialization script of a Dataproc cluster. Is it possible to update the cluster metadata or add a label to the cluster (without using `gcloud dataproc clusters update`) from within the script? Or any other method to write a more useful error message? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your goal to report an error message from within the init action that can be included in operation failure?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to report an error from within an initialization action, there is a  feature within Dataproc to extract messages from init action output.

As long as you emit a message in this format: `StructuredError{message}`

For example:

```
message="something went wrong"
echo "StructuredError{${message}}"
```